# Console Monopoly in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, game

I began to program the standard version of Monopoly so that it could be played only using the console. I did this to practice Object Oriented Programming and have little to no background experience designing or programming games.

The program is not complete yet but I felt that the program was good enough to share and ask for feedback at this point.

If anyone has any suggestions or any feedback on the design of my project or anything else they can think of, please drop a comment below.

```
from random import randint

class Dye(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def roll(self):
        return randint(0,6)

class Tile(object):
    """
    Data Attributes:
        name
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def trigger_event(self):
        print("Triggered Default Tile Event")

class Property(Tile):
    """
    Data Attributes:
        name
        price
        base_rent
        is_utility
        is_rr
        owner
    """

    def __init__(self, name, price, base_rent, is_utility=False, 
                 is_rr=False):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.base_rent = base_rent
        self.owner=None

        if(is_utility):
            self.is_utility = True
        if(is_rr):
            self.is_rr = True

    def trigger_event(self):
        if self.owner is None:
            print("You landed on an unowned property")

            while True:
                print("\n", "Unowned Property Menu")    
                Game.display_menu(Game.unowned_property_menu)
                selection = input("Select an option by typing a number: ")
                if selection == '1':
                    # Buy Property
                    if Game.current_player.balance >= self.price:
                        Game.current_player.owned_properties.append(self)
                        Game.current_player.balance -= self.price 
                        print("Congratulations!", Game.current_player.name, 
                              "has successfully bought", self.name, 
                              "for the price of", self.price)
                        Game.current_player.display_balance()
                    else:
                        print("Your balance of", Game.current_player.balance,
                              "is insufficient to buy", self.name, "at the price of",
                              self.price)

                    break    
                elif selection == '2':
                    # Do Not Buy Property
                    print("You chose not to buy {}.".format(self.name))
                    break
                else:
                   print("Unknown option selected!")

    def view_property(self):
        print(self.name)    

class Player(object):
    """
    Class Attributes:
        player_list
        max_num_players
    Data Attributes:
       name
       current_tile_index
       current_tile
       is_in_jail
       properties_owned       
       amount_of_money
    """
    player_list = []
    MAX_NUM_PLAYERS = 4

    def __init__(self, name):
        if len(Player.player_list) == Player.MAX_NUM_PLAYERS:
            print("Error: Cannot have more than", Player.MAX_NUM_PLAYERS, "players!") #DEBUG
        else:    
            self.name = name
            self.current_tile_index = 0
            self.current_tile = None # sets current tile to "GO" 
            self.is_in_jail = False
            self.num_rounds_in_jail = 0
            self.owned_properties = []
            self.balance = 1500

            Player.player_list.append(self)
            print(self.name, "has been succesfully added!") #DEBUG            

    def roll_and_move(self): # should a method from one class depend on a data attribute from another class?
        roll_1 = Game.DYE.roll()
        roll_2 = Game.DYE.roll()
        total_roll = roll_1 + roll_2
        print("You rolled a", roll_1) #DEBUG
        print("You rolled a", roll_2) #DEBUG

        # move player to new tile
        if total_roll + self.current_tile_index >= len(Game.BOARD):
            final_index = (self.current_tile_index + total_roll) - len(Game.BOARD) 
            self.current_tile_index = final_index
            self.current_tile = Game.BOARD[self.current_tile_index]
            self.balance += 200 # Pass GO
            print("You passed GO!") #DEBUG
        else:
            self.current_tile_index = self.current_tile_index + total_roll
            self.current_tile = Game.BOARD[self.current_tile_index]

        print("Your current tile is now",self.current_tile.name)    #DEBUG

        # trigger_event
        self.current_tile.trigger_event()

    def display_owned_properties(self):
        print("{}'s Properties: ".format(self.name))
        for property in self.owned_properties:
            print(property.name)

    def display_balance(self):
        print("{}'s current balance is {}".format(self.name, self.balance))

    def get_out_of_jail(self):
        pass

    """
    will put this in option function:

    def add_player():
        if len(Player.player_list) == Player.max_num_players:
            print("Error, cannot have more than",Player.max_num_players, "players")
            return
        else:
            print("You are adding a player")
            name = input('Please type the name of the player: ') # TODO: error check
            Player.player_list.append(Player(name))
            for player in Player.player_list: #DEBUG
                print(player.name, "successfully added!") 
    """


class Game(object):
    """ Instantiate once"""

    current_player = None
    turn_counter = 0
    DYE = Dye()
    BOARD = None   
    setup_menu = None
    player_menu = None
    unowned_property_menu = None


    def __init__(self):

        Game.BOARD = [
            Tile("GO"),
            Property("Mediterranean Avenue", 60, 2),
            Tile("Community Chest"),
            Property("Baltic Avenue",60, 8),
            Tile("Income Tax"),
            Property("Reading Railroad", 200, 50),
            Property("Oriental Avenue", 100, 6),
            Tile("Chance"),
            Property("Vermont Avenue", 100, 6),
            Property("Connecticut Avenue", 120, 8),
            Tile("Jail"),
            Property("St. Charles Place", 140, 10),
            Property("Electric Company", 150, 0, is_utility=True),
            Property("States Avenue", 140, 10),
            Property("Virginia Avenue", 160, 12),
            Property("Pennsylvania Railroad", 200, 50),
            Property("St. James Place", 180, 14),
            Tile("Community Chest"),
            Property("Tennessee Avenue", 180, 14),
            Property("New York Avenue", 200, 16),
            Tile("Free Parking"),
            Property("Kentucky Avenue", 220, 18),
            Tile("Chance"),
            Property("Indiana Avenue", 220, 18),
            Property("Illinois Avenue", 240, 20),
            Property("B. & O. Railroad", 200, 50),
            Property("Atlantic Avenue", 260, 22),
            Property("Ventnor Avenue", 260, 22),
            Property("Water Works", 150, 0, is_utility=True),
            Property("Marvin Gardens", 280, 24),
            Tile("Go To Jail"),
            Property("Pacific Avenue", 300, 26),
            Property("North Caroliina Avenue", 300, 26),
            Tile("Community Chest"),
            Property("Pennsylvania Avenue", 320, 28),
            Property("Short Line", 200, 50),
            Tile("Chance"),
            Property("Park Place", 350, 35),
            Tile("Luxury Tax"),
            Property("Boardwalk", 400, 50)]

        Game.setup_menu = {}
        Game.setup_menu['1'] = "Add Player." 
        Game.setup_menu['2'] = "Start Game."

        Game.player_menu = {}
        Game.player_menu['1'] = "Roll Dice."
        Game.player_menu['2'] = "Display Owned Properties."

        Game.unowned_property_menu = {}
        Game.unowned_property_menu['1'] = "Buy Property"
        Game.unowned_property_menu['2'] = "Do Not Buy Property"

        print("Welcome to Console Monopoly!")
        while True:
            print("\n")
            Game.display_menu(Game.setup_menu)
            selection = input("Select an option by typing a number: ")
            if selection == '1':
                player_name = input("Please enter player name: ")
                Player(player_name)
            elif selection == '2':
                if len(Player.player_list) == 0:
                    print("Error: Cannot start game without players")
                else:
                    break
            else:
               print("Unknown option selected!")

        Game.current_player = Player.player_list[0]
        self.main() # Starts Main Game

    @staticmethod
    def display_menu(menu: dict):
        for option in menu:
            print("{}. {}".format(option, menu[option]))


    def start_player_turn(self):
        if Game.current_player.is_in_jail:
            did_his_time = Game.current_player.num_turns_in_jail == 3
            if did_his_time:
                Game.current_player.get_out_of_jail()
            else:
                print("Haven't coded this bit yet!")
                #TODO:
                #increment current_player.num_turns_in_jail
                #display in_jail_menu
                #code logic for menu selections
        elif True==False: #if player is bankrupt/ has lost
            pass
        else:
            while True:
                print("\n", "Player Menu:")
                Game.display_menu(Game.player_menu)
                selection = input("Select an option by typing a number: ")
                if selection == '1':
                    # Player Rolls Dice and Moves
                    Game.current_player.roll_and_move()
                elif selection == '2':
                    # TODO:
                    print("TODO: Code diplay owned properties function")
                else:
                   print("Unknown option selected!")

    def end_player_turn(self):
        pass

    def main(self):
        while True:
            if Game.current_player.is_in_jail:
                self.end_player_turn()
            elif True == False: #TODO:make function that checks if there is a winner
                pass # all other players bankrupt, end game 
            else:
                self.start_player_turn()



if __name__ == "__main__":    
    Game()
```

Comment: By the way, it is spelt Die not Dye, just a little thing I noticed

Answer (score 4):

This is a quite a bit later than this question's post date, but perhaps this review can be useful to others. Note this review relatively surface-level; it doesn't delve into a complete dissection of how the program actually functions, but it does contain useful advice about general program structure. If the code was revised to incorporate the below feedback and asked as a new question, then further substantive critiques would be easier to make.

- Having docstrings is a nice touch, and generally a sign of a well-documented module. However, your docstrings are not very descriptive of what the classes are intended for, or what the various attributes represent. [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) is recommended reading for how to write descriptive (and standardized) docstrings.
- If you're using Python 3.x (which happens to be true, because you're using the `print` function without an import from `__future__`), classes with no superclass implicitly inherit from `object`, so there's never a need to have `object` as the superclass
- As @13ros27 mentions in comments, `Dye` should be `Die`
- Having an empty `__init__()` in `Die` is unnecessary because `__init__()` is empty by default.
- If you're using Python 3.7 or later (which was not released at the time of this question's asking), you can utilize [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/library/dataclasses.html) for less boilerplate `__init__()` attribute code and descriptive object representation. If you're using Python 3.6, there's also [a backport](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/).
- It would be slightly easier to read the closing `]` for `Game.Board` if it were on a separate line.
- If you have a condition that should always be false, don't do `elif True==False:`; just do `elif False:`. Generally you should just avoid absolute conditionals and leave a `TODO` comment there to add remind yourself to add it in later.

### Code smell: don't redefine class attributes as if they're instance attributes

It's really bad form to declare class attributes in `Board`'s `__init__` method because class attribute definitions only need to run once. There's no benefit to having such code in `__init__`. Sure, you might not instantiate `Board` multiple times *now*, but if you ever do later, there's no reason to have the code run twice. More importantly, it ruins the values of these attributes if you ever end up instantiating multiple `Board` objects in the same program.

In your case though, it seems like the attributes are intended to be instance attributes, and they should use `self` instead of the class's name. This antipattern is present throughout the code for `Board`: just **don't do it!** Class attributes that are reassigned should probably just be instance attributes.

The dictionaries in `__init__` can also be simplified. Instead of:

```
        Game.setup_menu = {}
        Game.setup_menu['1'] = "Add Player." 
        Game.setup_menu['2'] = "Start Game."

        Game.player_menu = {}
        Game.player_menu['1'] = "Roll Dice."
        Game.player_menu['2'] = "Display Owned Properties."

        Game.unowned_property_menu = {}
        Game.unowned_property_menu['1'] = "Buy Property"
        Game.unowned_property_menu['2'] = "Do Not Buy Property"
```

Just do this (with the names appropriate to the context):

```
        setup_menu = {'1': "Add Player." , '2': "Start Game."}
        player_menu = {'1': "Roll Dice.", '2': "Display Owned Properties."}
        unowned_property_menu = {'1': "Buy Property", '2': "Do Not Buy Property"}
```

Speaking of `Board`'s `__init__` method...

### Limit the amount of code in `__init__`

You shouldn't have code that starts a game in `__init__`. `__init__` should contain just the bare minimum necessities to declare the object. The reason for this is [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). As it currently stands, most of the code in `__init__` should be moved into a separate `setup_game()` and `play_game()` methods. At the very least, you should have to explicitly run a `play_game()` to start the game, not just instantiate a `Board` object.